# Set specify IP for a Docker container from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
web_server:
    build: web_server/
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    links:
        - mongo
    tty: true
    environment:
        SYMFONY__MONGO_ADDRESS: mongo
        SYMFONY__MONGO_PORT: 27017
    networks:
        app_net:
           ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
           ipv6_address: 2001:3984:3989::10

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    enable_ipv6: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
      -
        subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64

mongo:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: mongo
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    expose:
        - 27017
```

I want to have a specifiy IP for my web_server for pass this in another applications.

But when I call command `docker-compose up` I recive the error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for networks: 'app_net'
Unsupported config option for web_server: 'networks'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't known why you have this error but you can try to fix some points:

1. webserver networks must refer the networks declared below
2. you simplify your network configuration and start with ipv4 only

Here is a working configuration:

```
version: '2'

services:

  webssl:
    image: nginx:1.11.4-alpine
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /data/nginx/webroot:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    networks:
      - dmz

networks:
  dmz:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.77.0.1/24
          ip_range: 172.77.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.77.0.1
```

Comment: I tried to add to my `docker-compose.yml` file but doesn't work.